# Table layout with 4 columns in HTML not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, xhtml

I am common table layout return in pure html which has 4 columns

```
    <table>
<colgroup span="1" width="20%"/>
<colgroup span="1" width="30%"/>
<colgroup span="1" width="20%"/>
<colgroup span="1" width="30%"/>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
question data.......
</td>
<td colspan="1">
Answer data......
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
question data.......
</td>
<td colspan="2">
Answer data......
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This layout should work fine with first row columns should have width of 70 and 30% resp
and second row should have width of 50 and 50 resp. But the output what i see different. 
what could be the problem and how to fix it. I couple of solutions for it 
1. defining width at column level will work
2. defining a blank row with four columns above or below.

But Why is this happening?

Comment: When I view your code in Chrome 6, the cell widths seem to match what you’re aiming for. Not so much in IE 6 though.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, assigning a column width when using colspan doesn't work. I don't know why, but the width spec seems to be ignored - anyway, it never seems to do what you would expect.

Comment: I've always found that `col` and `colgroup` are very *meta*, rather than of much practical use in current browsers (so far as I've experimented).

Comment: Yeah — this is why I always thought it was weird how some people didn’t like using CSS for layout, and wanted to stick to tables. Table layout behaviour can be mind-bending.

Comment: To meet Section 508 we have to use table for layout instead divs

Comment: @Praneeth: I haven’t looked at Section 508 in a while, but what you just said sounds like utter drivel.

Comment: @Paul: Why do u think...I am asking whether it is doable or not. I got to implement this. If not I could propose different solution

Comment: @Praneeth: why do I think what? That your claim about section 508 is drivel? Because 508 is a set of accessibility guidelines based on WCAG version 1. I can’t imagine them suggesting using tables for layout instead of CSS. Could you point to the part of Section 508 that says you have to use tables for layout?

Comment: @Praneeth: [the homepage of whitehouse.gov](http://www.whitehouse.gov/) doesn’t include a single `<table>` tag. Is whitehouse.gov in breach of section 508?

Comment: @Paul:Ok I can explain why I said that I converting a form (like 2 physical pages) with bunch of question and answer I put that into logical grouping now i having 6 pages which just bunch of question and answers. Some where on Stack for displaying just such information blind people reader can't read that information properly like this is a question and this a textbox for that. I love to use div's. Please correct if am wrong here. I am not section 508 expert.

Comment: I like col and colgroup for styling, but not so much for width.

Comment: @Ray: The problem is with the width. when i have above mentioned scenario. For the rest its just perfect

Comment: “blind people reader can't read that information properly like this is a question and this a textbox for that” — ah! I see! Sure: to allow screen readers (for blind people) to know which question goes with which form field, you’d use `<label for="question1">Question</label> <textarea id="question1"></textarea>`. You can (and should) do this with any type of form field.

Comment: There’s a good article here about accessible forms, although it is in English: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: Bear in mind that you can only use `<label>` with form fields though. If your questions and answers aren’t in fact part of the form, and are just like a list of FAQs, then you just want each question to be a heading (e.g. `<h2>`, `<h3>`).

Comment: @Paul, for that last example I'd suggest using a `dl` for FAQs, although your points about semantics are well made, especially as regards Section 508.

Comment: @David: yeh, that would work too, as per http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element.